# ChromeOS 56 disabling flash for kiosk app

Tags: flash, google-chrome-app

We have a custom internal kiosk app that runs a flash app, which has worked great until the latest OS update. After ChromeOS 56 update, all it will show is a download button for flash, which obviously isn't helpful in a kiosk app on a ChromeOS device. With the new push to disable flash in Chrome use, there must have been some change where ChromeOS is telling the web server it's talking to that it doesn't even have flash, let alone any option to allow it to run, and I'm struggling to find any domain policy or manifest kind of permission that would allow it to run in the kiosk app. Is there any workaround so that that flash app in that published kiosk app can be forced to always be allowed to load?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm on Raspbian with a chromium kiosk app which is asking me to enable flash. Uhhuh.. without a keyboard ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're displaying the Flash content via a direct link to the SWF file? Either the whole address bar points to some SWF url, or else you have an i-frame that's pointing to same SWF url?

**solution :**

- Embed the SWF inside an html container. Your address bar or i-frame should point to an html file (html itself has code to embed the SWF).
- Embed size of SWF must be minimum W=800 by H=600.
- Make sure the SWF is coming from `https` location.